# SQL using where and as multiple times in one column

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to create multiple columns from one column creating different column names. I'll post something I tried but didn't work -

```
SELECT sample, specimen_id
     , (amp as amp1 from schema.table where amp1 ilike 'amp1%' and read >= 100), 
    (amp as amp2 from schema.table where amp ilike 'amp2%' and read >= 100)
    from schema.table
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT sample, specimen_id
    , amp as amp1 from schema.table where amp1 ilike 'amp1%' and read >= 100, 
    AND amp as amp2 from schema.table where amp ilike 'amp2%' and read >= 100
    from schema.table
```

I have to do this for 5 different genes. But basically I just need to chop up the "amp" column based on it's first few characters.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: i don't know which database system you are using , but for that you will need dynamic sql

Comment: sample input data, and desired output data should make this question easier to answer.

Comment: Are you looking for self joins?

Comment: what do you mean by "chop up"?  that sounds like pulling out substrings but it's impossible to tell from what you've given us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is syntactically incorrect, but you also have a logical error. First, let's delve into the logical error.

When you consider a record in a table and load its fields, such as `sample` and `specimen_id`, you cannot link these values to your `amp` value, unless there is a single such value. Since you attempted to write a subselect, there is no guarantee that `amp` will be unique, so, you attempt to link a record to possibly multiple records.

You will need to perform some join, like

```
SELECT t.sample, t.specimen_id, t1.amp as amp1, t2.amp as amp2
from schema.table t
join schema.table t1
on t.sample = t1.sample and t.specimen = t.specimen,
join schema.table t2
on t.sample = t2.sample and t.specimen = t2.specimen,
where (t1.amp ilike 'amp1%' and t1.read >= 100) and
      (t2.amp ilike 'amp2%' and t2.read >= 100)
```

But it's possible that you want to group by them in some manner, like:

```
SELECT t.sample, t.specimen_id, group_concat(t1.amp) as amp1, group_concat(t2.amp) as amp2
from schema.table t
join schema.table t1
on t.sample = t1.sample and t.specimen = t1.specimen,
join schema.table t2
on t.sample = t2.sample and t.specimen = t2.specimen,
where (t1.amp ilike 'amp1%' and t1.read >= 100) and
      (t2.amp ilike 'amp2%' and t2.read >= 100)
group by t.sample, t.specimen_id
```

The functions above are MySQL functions, if you are using a different RDBMS, then you can change the call to these functions to the ones that actually exist in your RDBMS.

Comment: Lajos, thank you so much. I had to mess with it a bit (i gave made up terms) but this gave me a great starting point.

BTW, i'm using dbeaver, and had to just use a concat command instead of group_concat. I should have made that clear in the original post.

Comment: @ThewGuy happy to help! If this answer helped you solving your problem, then you can accept it as the correct answer. If the solution was not quite reached yet, then please let me know.

Comment: I marked it as solved. I do want to add though that I get a memory error when trying to add a third join, it’s probably my  syntax though

Comment: @ThewGuy memory errors are generally beyond the syntax. The engine first evaluates whether your syntax is correct and all the references can be interpreted and once it concludes in the affirmative, only then is executing the actual query. Memory errors therefore seem to suggest that the problem-space was too large, i.e., too much memory storage was used in order to process it, exceeding the allowed limits. So, the problem in the question seems to be solved and you seem to have a follow-up problem. You might want to ask a new question and share its link here, so I will look it up as well.

Comment: @ThewGuy also, you have mentioned you are using DBeaver, which is a client software. Can you tell us whish RDBMS are you connecting to?